# How to get index number of associative array that has a value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this associative array in php,

```
Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Desc] => Tech Pen [Qty] => 15 ) [1] => Array ( [Desc] => Ballpen [Qty] => 4 ) ) )
```

How to get the index number that has a Description value of Tech Pen?

The answer should be, [0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to get your index number is to loop the `$array` using a `foreach`:

```
$array = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "Desc" => "Tech Pen",
            "Qty" => 15
        ),
        array(
            "Desc" => "Ballpen",
            "Qty" => 4
        ),
    )
);

foreach ($array['items'] as $key => $item) {
    if($item['Desc'] === 'Tech Pen') {
        echo "The value 'Tech Pen' has index number: $key";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **array_search()** — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful. [Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Try:

```
$key=array_search('Tech Pen', $array);
```